# Screen reader not reading text within header tag

Tags: wai-aria

I have a header tag that contains the title of the page. The Windows screen reader is not reading that text and i wanted to know if there is a way to do so by adding some aria items?

```
<section class="section">
    <header class="section-title" ip-l10n="county_list">List of Countries</header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, there are **headings** and **headers**.  Headings are `<h1>` through `<h6>` elements.  Headers are typically used when describing tables and are the names at the top of the column, the column **header** or `<th>` tag.

You had mentioned that your header contained the "title of the page".  The title of the page is normally contained in a **heading**, specifically an `<h1>` if it's the main title of the page.  So I wasn't clear which term you were really asking about.

I know your example used the `<header>` element so I will limit my comments to just that element, but I did want to point out the aforementioned differences to make sure we're all talking about the same thing.  Accessibility and aria tags are all about semantics so it's good to be clear about the semantics of your question.

The [`<header>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-header-element) element is a container for stuff that's usually at the top of your page.  By default, it creates a [`banner`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#banner) landmark.  A `<header>` usually contains a `<nav>` which is the main navigation for the site that is repeated on all pages.  It might also contain the company logo as an image and serves as a link back to the home page.  It might also have account info, or if a retail site, the shopping cart contents.  So a `<header>` might have interactive and non-interactive things.

In your example code, you just have plain text in your header.  That's not interactive so a screen reader user will not hear the text if they are using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to navigate the site.  They **will** hear the text if they navigate the DOM using the up/down arrow keys with the screen reader.

If instead, you really meant for your code to be a **heading**, and thus the `<h1>` tag, that is also static text that is not interactive so again, the screen reader user will not hear the text if they are using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to navigate the site.  However, they **can** hear the text if they use the screen reader <kbd>H</kbd> quicknav key (to navigate to a **heading**).

So if you want to clarify your question, I can update my answer.